# Difference equation with log

Tags: recurrence-relations

Can we find continuous $f(x)$ and $d$ such that $$ f(x+1)-f(x) = -\log( c|x| + d ) $$ 
for all $x$? The constant $c>0$ is specified.

Comment: Is $x$ an arbitrary real number? Does $f$ have to be continuous?

Comment: @5xum He stated that $f$ is continuous, and said for all $x$.

Comment: @KristofferRyhl He sure did. After I posted the comment. Also, for all $x$ may still mean "for all $x\in\mathbb R$".

Comment: I think I'm pretty much there with Log Gamma

Answer (score 1):

$f(x+1)-f(x)=-\log(c|x|+d)$

$f(x)=\Theta(x)-\sum\limits_x\log(c|x|+d)$ , where $\Theta(x)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period

$f(x)=\Theta(x)-\log\prod\limits_x(c|x|+d)$ , where $\Theta(x)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period